# What's the meaning of the coordinates if we use a polar coordinate system?

Tags: vector-spaces, coordinate-systems

In general, the coordinates of a vector are defined as the projections of it onto the coordinate axis. Moreover, in a polar coordinate system, the basis vectors $\hat e_\phi$, $\hat e_r$ depend on the location.

For concreteness, let's assume that we want to describe an object that starts at $\vec a=(1,1)_{x,y}=(\sqrt{2},45^\circ)_{r,\phi}$ and ends at $\vec a=(1,-1)_{x,y}=(\sqrt{2},-45^\circ)_{r,\phi}$.

[image]

How can we understand the coordinates in the polar coordinate system in terms of projections onto the coordiante axis, $\hat e_\phi$, $\hat e_r$? In particular, which basis vectors do we use? (This is nontrivial since the basis vectors $\hat e_\phi$, $\hat e_r$ depend on the location. Therefore, if we use the basis vectors at the location our vectors point to, we always find zero for the projection onto $\hat e_\phi$ which is obviously wrong.)

Answer (score 1):

The angle is usually called $\theta$ in $2$ dimensions.

The result $\vec{r}=r\vec{e}_r$ isn't a bug, it's a feature. Since $\vec{e}_r=\cos\theta\vec{e}_i+\sin\theta\vec{e}_j$ and $\vec{e}_\theta=-\sin\theta\vec{e}_i+\cos\theta\vec{e}_j$, $\frac{d}{d\theta}\vec{e}_r=\vec{e}_\theta$ and $\frac{d}{d\theta}\vec{e}_\theta=-\vec{e}_r$, so $\frac{d}{d\theta}\vec{r}=\frac{dr}{d\theta}\vec{e}_r+r\vec{e}_\theta$.

If $\theta$ is time-dependent, $\dot{\vec{r}}=\dot{\theta}\frac{d}{d\theta}\vec{r}$ by the chain rule. This is useful in kinematics, where we can also obtain $\ddot{\vec{r}}=\left(\ddot{r}-r\dot{\theta}^2\right)\vec{e}_r+\frac1r\frac{d}{dt}\left(r^2\dot{\theta}\right)\vec{e}_\theta$. If we [move into three dimensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylindrical_coordinate_system) viz. the right-hand rule $\vec{e}_z:=\vec{e}_r\times\vec{e}_\theta$, $\vec{r}\times\dot{\vec{r}}=r^2\dot{\theta}\vec{e}_z$. Thus angular momentum is conserved if the acceleration is radial, [which is very useful](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binet_equation).

Edit: I'll discuss [how we get basis vectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvilinear_coordinates#Covariant_and_contravariant_bases) for general coordinates.

Let $x^i$ denote a Cartesian coordinate system and $q^i$ an alternative coordinate system, and define the *covariant basis* $\vec{b}_i:=\frac{\partial\vec{r}}{\partial q^i}$ and *contravariant basis* $\vec{b}^j:=\vec{\nabla}q^j$ so$$\vec{b}_i\cdot\vec{b}^j=\frac{\partial x^k}{\partial q^i}\frac{\partial q^j}{\partial x^k}=\frac{\partial q^j}{\partial q^i}=\delta_i^j.$$In the polar example$$q^1=r,\,q^2=\theta,\,\vec{b}_1=\vec{e}_r,\,\vec{b}_2=r\vec{e}_\theta,\,\vec{b}^1=\vec{e}_r,\,\vec{b}^2=\frac1r\vec{e}_\theta.$$

Comment: But wouldn't this imply that the $\theta$-component of any "position vector" (i.e. a vector that points from the origin to some location) is zero?

Comment: @jak Yes, *that's the point*. It's vectors *other* than $\vec{r}$ that make use of $\vec{e}_\theta$, as per my examples. For example, if $\vec{r}$ describes a particle's position, we define the unit vectors from that, but the velocity then has a $\theta$ component in general.

Comment: thanks! I still find it quite strange that all these different positions are labeled in polar coordinates with exactly the same numbers. Given the coordinates $(\sqrt{2},0^\circ)_{r,\theta}$ how do we we know which position it corresponds to? From the discussion above it seems as if all positions lying on the circle with radius $\sqrt{2}$ are equally good candidates. But shouldn't the $\theta$ coordinate tells us where exactly we are on the circle?

Comment: @jak The point with coordinates $(r,\, theta)$ in the polar coordinate system is $r\vec{e}_r$ rather than $r\vec{e}_r+\theta$r\vec{e}_\theta$$, which is what a Cartesian intuition might suggest. The real benefit of $\vec{\theta}$ is in describing differential operators, e.g. $\vec{\nabla}=\vec{e}_r\partial_r+\vec{e}_\theta\frac1r\partial_\theta$ in $2$ dimensions. This may be confusing at first, but it helps when you get to such concepts as the vector-as-operator notion $v:=v^a\partial_a$.

Comment: Sorry, that comment should have begun: "The point with coordinates $(r,\,\theta)$ in the polar coordinate system is $r\vec{e}_r$ rather than $r\vec{e}_r+\theta\vec{e}_\theta$".

Comment: I'm still making some probably obvious thinking error, but thanks to your answer and comments I think I'm now able to finally pin down what is bothering me.The coordinates of the two points indicated in the illustration above are $(\sqrt{2},45^\circ)_{r,\phi}$ and $(\sqrt{2},-45^\circ)_{r,\phi}$. But these aren't the projections of the vectors $\vec a$ and $\vec b$ onto the coordinate axes at the correpsonding locations. As argued above, these are $(\sqrt{2},0^\circ)_{r,\phi}$ and $(\sqrt{2},0^\circ)_{r,\phi}$.

Comment: So my question really is: how can we understand the "correct" coordinates, $(\sqrt{2},45^\circ)_{r,\phi}, (\sqrt{2},-45^\circ)_{r,\phi}$ of the two points in terms of projections onto coordinate axes?

Comment: @jak *You can't*. They don't describe vectors' coefficients. There's no constraint on *how* a coordinate system can tell you where a point is; different systems do it differently. Here it says, "go this far  from the origin in this direction". You can think of $\theta$ as measuring position along the constant-$r$ circumference, but that distance is traversed in a continually changing direction, so the path is really a definite $\theta$-integral over a $\theta$-dependent vector. This generalises the vector-times-number approach in Cartesian coordinates.

Comment: Thanks! Just one last quick question: does this change when we consider a vector field $\vec v(\vec x)$ which assigns a vector to each point in our, say, two dimensional real space $\mathbb R^2$? I can imagine that in this case, we need to use the projections onto the coordinate axes at the corresponding locations to determine the coordinates of $\vec v(\vec x)$ in spherical coordinates?!

Comment: @jak So for example, if $v=\dot{r}$ you get the projections I described above.